# React: Passing props between components is always undefined - Context API

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I'm trying to pass some data to another component, i'm able to console.log() it in both of them and appears to be an Object on the second, but when i try to use it the system says that it's undefined

```
import React, { useEffect, useContext, Fragment } from 'react';
import BackgroundContext from '../../context/background/backgroundContext'
import Background from './Background'
import Spinner from './Spinner'

export const Photos = () => {
  const backgroundContext = useContext(BackgroundContext);

  const { photos, loading } = backgroundContext;

  if (loading) {
    return <Spinner />;
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <Background key={photos.id} photos={photos[0]} /> //    sending the data
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Photos
```

And the another component:

```
import React, { useContext, Component } from 'react';
import Spinner from './Spinner';

const Background = ( {photos} ) => {
    const { img_src} = photos;

    const bg = {
        backgroundImage: `url(${photos.img_src})`,
        height: '100vh',
        position: 'relative'
    };    

    return (
        <div style={bg}>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Background;
```

The background context:

```
import { createContext } from 'react';

const backgroundContext = createContext();

export default backgroundContext;
```

And an example of the object:
[Print of the console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/febHT.png)

And the backgroundState: https://codeshare.io/50WVMm

Comment: Can you share the code from `BackgroundContext`?

Comment: ok, just added.

Comment: Your context gets initialized with value `undefined`. Have you created a provider component that is higher up in the component hierarchy? Please share how `backgroundContext.Provider` gets the value of `photos` and `loading`.

Comment: Added an external link subashMahapatra

Comment: Try this snippet `if (!loading) { console.log(photos) }` in the `Photos` component and let me know if you see the desired result for photos or it is still an empty array.

Comment: Yes, it shows without problems - https://imgur.com/a/c0NBzqp . The funny point is, through my tests if i "map" these 2 arrays i'm able to get the "img_src", but my goal is to get only one

Comment: Try this snippet and let me know if it resolved the issue. `return (
      <div>
        {photos.length && <Background key={photos.id} photos={photos[0]} />}
      </div>
    )`

Comment: subashMahapatra it really worked!

Comment: Where is your context provide?

Comment: Nice, I will be posting the answer and the explanation for why the strange behavior occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `initialState` for background state is defined as,

```
const initialState = {
   photos: [],
   loading: false
};
```

So when the `Photos` component renders for the first time, the initial state value for `photos` is passed from the `backgroundContext` which is an empty array that's why when trying to access `photos[0]` it produces the error.

The solution, check for the `photos.length` in a conditional and then pass `photos[0]` as prop to `Background` component.

```js
export const Photos = () => {
  const backgroundContext = useContext(BackgroundContext);

  const { photos, loading } = backgroundContext;

  if (loading) {
    return <Spinner />;
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        {
         photos.length && <Background key={photos.id} photos={photos[0]} />
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```